# Reference Request : $q^{th}$ powers modulo $\ell$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Assume that $q$ is an odd prime and $p$ be a prime different from $q$. I would like to find the reference for the following fact:

There exists infinitely many primes $\ell$ such that the set $\{p, p^{2}, \ldots, p^{q-1}\}$ does not contain a $q^{th}$ power modulo $\ell$.

The proof of this fact is fairly straightforward. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^{q} - p $, which is irreducible because $p$ is not a $q^{th}$ power in rational (perhaps needs some reference). $f$ has the splitting field $K = \mathbb{Q}\big(p^{1/q}, \zeta_{q}\big)$ and the Galois group $G$ of the extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is $\simeq$ to semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ and $\big(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\big)^{\times}$. The $(q-1)$ generators of the automorphism group $\mathbb{Q}\big(p^{1/q}, \zeta_{q}\big)/\mathbb{Q}\big(\zeta_{q}\big)$ is a conjugacy class in $G$. Therefore, the Chebotarev’s density theorem implies that there exists a set of primes $\ell$ of density $\frac{q-1}{q(q-1)} = \frac{1}{q}$ such that the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo $\ell$.

I am writing an article and would like to quote this fact from a reference, rather than adding this elementary fact as a lemma. Does anyone know of a reference for the above fact?

Comment: Why do you want a citation, much better to mention that it suffices to apply Chebotarev to $\Bbb{Q}(p^{1/q},\zeta_q)$.

Comment: I would like to avoid doing so unless I can name a good reference, since the article is for readers who may not be quite initiated in this area.

Comment: Why does the subject line refer to $q$th powers modulo $p$ when the question is about $q$th powers modulo $\ell$? Please fix that.  For what it's worth, the property you ask about does not require $p$ to be a prime. It works with $p$ replaced by an integer $a$ that is not a $q$th power, since for an arbitrary field $F$, with $a \in F^\times$, $x^q - a$ for prime $q$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if it has no root in $F$ (and taking $F = \mathbf Q$, every rational root of a monic in $\mathbf Z[x]$ has to be an integer).

Comment: For a field $F$, $\alpha \in F^\times$, and relatively prime positive integers $m$ and $n$, $\alpha^m$ is an $n$th power in $F$ if and only if $\alpha$ is an $n$th power in $F$. So if $n = q$ is prime, none of $\alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^{q-1}$ are $q$th powers in $F$ if and only if $\alpha$ is not a $q$th power in $F$. Thus you are asking for a reference showing that *if $x^q - a$ is irreducible in $\mathbf Z[x]$, then $x^q-a \bmod \ell$ is irreducible in $\mathbf F_\ell[x]$ for infinitely many primes $\ell$*. That's a conceptually simpler way to express the fact that interests you.